# How to structure templated function with inner templates?

Tags: c++, templates

I am trying to create a templated function that takes in any types of object which in of itself are also templated. An example is:

```
ObjA<int, string> o;
ObjB<float, int> o2;
```

I want to make a function that takes any of these types of objects but am unsure how to structure the template. This is my bad attempt:

```
template<typename T, typename U, typename V>
    void Add(std::shared_ptr<V<T, U>> inst) {
    
    }
```

Comment: Are you familiar with [**template template parameters**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters#Template_template_parameter)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to turn `V` into a [template template parameter](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters#Template_template_parameter):

```
template<typename T, typename U, template<typename, typename> typename V>
void Add(std::shared_ptr<V<T, U>> inst) {

}
```

Note that this restricts `V` to having two template arguments. Your goal of making a "templated function that takes in any types of object which in of itself are also templated" does not specify that limit; to allow `V` to have any amount of template parameters you can do this:

```
template<template<typename...> typename V, typename... Ts>
void Add(std::shared_ptr<V<Ts...>> inst) {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's called [template template parameter](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters#Template_template_parameter) and here is an example of what u r trying to do

```
template<typename T, typename U, template<typename T1 = T, typename T2 = U > typename V>
void Add(std::shared_ptr<V<T, U>> inst) {

}
```